# Receiving unfair results in setting same size for width and height in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Normally my gui look like below

[image]

I tried to implement same size for width and height in Get button.  But the result is unfair (see the image below)

[image]

code snippet i tried

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner); 

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1); 
    spinner.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.row, strings));

    Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.getbtn);
    int x = btn.getLayoutParams().height;
    btn.getLayoutParams().width = x;
}
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:gravity="center">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Testing" 
        />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:prompt="@string/prompt"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/getbtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="Get"
        />

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to solve this issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your layout XMl.

Comment: @HamidShatu I updated with xml

Comment: what are you actually want to do?

Comment: I want to set same size for both width and height of 'Get' button (In first image width of get button is smaller than height )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving `fill_parent` to the `android:layout_height` attribute to the `Button` XML. So, when you programmtically set that `height` value to `width` of `Button` then the `Button` taking so large `width` to fill the parent width.

Now, change the following attribute of `Button`

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create custom button, overriding `onMeasure()` as below:

```
public class SquareHeightButton extends Button {
    ...
    ...
    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

Comment: i just need a simple implementation.  So i go with Hamid Shatu.  Anyway thanks